# Solr query results with mixed types

Tags: search, solr, facet, solrcloud

We are using Solr 6.6 and have documents in our index with 2 different types: `book` and `movie`.  I'd like to run a search that would return 10 results per page.  The first 3 results should be matching `book` docs and the last 7 results should be matching `movie` docs.  Then on page 2 it would have 3 more `book` docs with 7 `movie` docs.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible with a Solr query?  I'm trying to avoid 2 separate queries, one for 3 `books` per page and 1 for 7 `movies` per page.  So doing this in a single query would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

We assume you have some 'type' field that says if a doc is a movie or book. Given that:

- what you really want is [diversity in results](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6066). This is for Lucene, unfortunately there is no Solr layer on top to take advantage yet.
- so your next best thing is [Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping), by asking for more docs than you need, then grouping by type, and hoping you have at least 3 books and 7 movies in each group (you might not). You can always fall back to a second query if you are missing some books or movies. It probably will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I have a `type` field.  I've looked into grouping.  I see the `group.limit` setting, but that seems like it would pull the same amount of docs for each type (i.e. 5 `books` and 5 `movies`).  Is there a way to specify 3 of one type and 7 of another?

Comment: no, just ask for 7 and then filter to 3 books on the client side

Comment: That works for the first page of results, but after that, the offsets won't be correct.